# Fastest way to read numerical values from text file in C++ (double in this case)

Tags: c++

Currently, my code is simply this:

```
void ReadFile(double Cst[][1000], char* FileName, int height)

FILE* ifp;
double value;
int nRead = 0;
int mRead = 0;

//open the file, check if successful
ifp = fopen( FileName, "r" );
if (ifp==NULL){
    ...
}


for (nRead = 0; nRead < height; nRead++){
    for (mRead = 0; mRead < 1000; mRead++){
        fscanf(ifp, "%le",&value);
        Cst[nRead][mRead]=value;
    }
}

fclose(ifp);
```

What can I change to make it the fastest possible?

Comment: `fscanf` handles a lot of fancy formatting: plus or minus sign, capital or lowercase `E` for exponent, etc. What does your numerical data actually look like?

Comment: Sample: 1.1028315e+002 -1.1063956e+002 -1.1099859e+002 -1.1136026e+002 -1.1172458e+002

Comment: Why label the code C++ if there is no C++ in it. It is plain C. Do you want C or C++ solution? And why are you so concerned about parsing performance when reading from file is bottleneck here?

Comment: First, I am nub, 2nd C++/C make no diff to me, 3rd it interests me and I find it frustrating to wait for the values to load whenever I start my app.

Comment: Not a duplicate but worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion

Comment: Not a duplicate but worth a read. [Whats the difference between c and c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640657/whats-the-difference-between-c-and-c)

Comment: Reading the file is going to be your bottleneck not the ability to parse integers. I would even use the C++ >> operator unless I could show the fcanf is significantly faster (I know it is faster but it needs to be significant for me to think it is worth while using it).

Comment: @Martin: @jdv posted a link to my question, which finds a factor of 6x performance advantage for stdio over stringstreams.  And neither one was as fast as the disk.  @Serge: Reading from file is not the bottleneck, and I actually have profiler data to prove that.  Where is your data?

Comment: Kristopher posted an answer suggesting the disk I/O was by far the slowest and deleted it in response to comments, but not before making the point that at least he wasn't suggesting iostreams.  So I find it ironic that now we have a plurality of answers suggesting exactly that.

Comment: Disk speed is irrelevant not only because there are data sources besides the disk, and fast RAIDs and solid-state drives, but also because disk caching tends often works magic.

Comment: Contrarily to your related question, this one doesn't provide proper grounds for benchmarks.

Comment: @Andre: True, this question doesn't have a compilable benchmark.  But when you find out `stringstream` is a factor of 50 slower than a custom int->string conversion, and a profiler shows most of the time is spent on thread synchronization (for a stream that isn't shared between threads), it's safe to apply that lesson to other operations based on the same `stringstream`, and conclude it's going to be slower at parsing as well.  It doesn't matter how fast the rest of `stringstream` is, the buffer lock is too slow to keep pace with a disk.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yeah, my question (linked by jdv) used a 100MB/s spinning disk as a performance target, but I was really trying to reach the 200+MB/s throughput of my SSD.  Still haven't got there on my tool, but did get an order of magnitude (application-wide) improvement by ditching iostreams.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I get a factor of about 10 difference between operator>> and scanf(" %ld"). But that does not mean it is significant. If I read one number I don't `feel` any difference. If I read a million; (2.5sec Vs 22 sec) now I begin to worry depending on how long the rest of the code runs. If the reset of the code takes 22 minutes I am not going to care; if the rest of the code takes 22 seconds I would care.

Comment: @Martin: Read the question again.  Here there are clearly many thousands of numbers being converted.  And startup cost, which Simon said this is, tends to be much more annoying.  If you have to set some options, the time waiting for that screen to appear is *your* time.  While time spent after settings are specified is just computer time, you can walk away and do something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`atof` is probably much faster, it doesn't have to process the format string.

If you don't need to support all 1001 recognized input formats (with and without exponents, etc) then a custom function may be faster yet.  If `atof` is still too slow for you, say so and I can clean up the code I use (it's not really suitable for public posting at the moment).

---

I just remembered the problem with `atof` -- it doesn't tell you where the number ended, so reading several numbers in sequence is difficult.  `strtod` is better in that regard.

Comment: So i would do `char c[255]; char * pEnd` at the beginning and:  `fscanf(ifp,"%s",&c); value = strtod(c,&pEnd)`; in the loop instead of `fscanf(ifp,"%le",value)`?

Comment: @Simon: No, you'd use `fread` (or memory mapped files) to grab a whole bunch of numbers into memory as text, and then `strtod` until you converted the whole buffer, then `fread` again.

Answer (score 18):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/).[QI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/quick_start.html) comes with a [benchmark](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/workbench/qi/real_parser.cpp) that compares the performance of `std::atof`, `std::strtod`, and `boost::spirit::qi::double_`. Here are the results on my system, using VC++ 2010 SP1 x64 and Boost 1.46.1:

> `atof_test`: 4.1579 seconds
>   `strtod_test`: 4.2339 seconds
>   `spirit_qi_double_test`: 1.2822 seconds

This puts Spirit.QI at **230% faster** than the next fastest *verifiable<sup>*****</sup>* option and **224% faster** than the next fastest unverifiable option – pretty fast, I'd say!

<sub>***** Unlike `std::atof`, `std::strtod` and Boost.Spirit will let you know whether or not the input was valid.</sub>

---

**Update:** I've rerun the benchmark, additionally using [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/).[X3](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/)'s `boost::spirit::x3::double_`; here are the results on my present system, using VC++ 2015 Update 3 x64 and Boost 1.61.0:

> `atof_test`: 2.2874 seconds
>   `strtod_test`: 2.2923 seconds
>   `spirit_qi_double_test`: 0.4849 seconds
>   `spirit_x3_double_test`: 0.4308 seconds

This puts Spirit.QI at 373% faster than the next fastest verifiable option and 372% faster than the next fastest unverifiable option, and Spirit.X3 at **432% faster** than the next fastest verifiable option and **431% faster** than the next fastest unverifiable option – things have improved *significantly* for Spirit, and on top of that, the X3-based code compiles in about ⅕ of the time as the QI-based code, so wins all around there as well!

Additionally, I've benchmarked the code in [@Potatoswatter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5679087/636019) (modified with double-precision exponent table and support for negative numbers ([code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d35ee14f25cc47d))), [@6502's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5832882/636019), and [@Mehrdad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21043991/636019), with the same build and test environment. Here are the results (@6502's code excluded as half of my sample inputs use scientific notation, which his code does not support):

> `potatoswatter_test`: 0.2358 seconds
>   `mehrdad_test`: 0.3415 seconds

If all inputs are converted to fixed notation, we can test @6502's code as well:

> `atof_test`: 3.6249 seconds
>   `strtod_test`: 3.7023 seconds
>   `spirit_qi_double_test`: 1.0763 seconds
>   `spirit_x3_double_test`: 2.3657 seconds
>   `potatoswatter_test`: 0.8347 seconds
>   `6502_test`: 4.1463 seconds
>   `mehrdad_test`: 1.3471 seconds

One note of interest is that QI fails to parse some very long fixed-notation inputs; X3 parses these correctly, but runs significantly slower than with short scientific-notation inputs.

Comment: Of course, like all boost spirit, the benchmark does not take into account the compile time :) My advice is to store this in a specific source file, to limit the times it's recompiled :)

Comment: Boost spirit's `double_` parser crashes from `array out of bounds` for any large values like "1e400" etc :\

Answer (score 16):

For an example, here is a very fast number parser from one of my projects. It only handles a very small subset of the actual features of the Standard Library numeric parsing.

```
uint64_t mystrtol( char *&pen, uint64_t val = 0 ) {
    for ( char c; ( c = *pen ^ '0' ) <= 9; ++ pen ) val = val * 10 + c;
    return val;
}

value_t mystrtof( char *&pen ) {
    static value_t const exp_table[]
     = { 1e5, 1e4, 1e3, 1e2, 10, 1, 0.1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6, 1e-7, 1e-8, 1e-9, 1e-10, 1e-11, 1e-12, 1e-13, 1e-14, 1e-15, 1e-16, 1e-17 },
     * exp_lookup = & exp_table[ 5 ];

    while ( iswspace( * ++ pen ) ) ;
    //if ( *pen == '-' ) ++ pen; // don't think we ever care about negative numbers
    uint64_t val = mystrtol( pen );
    int neg_exp = 0;
    if ( *pen == '.' ) { // mainly happens when val = 0
        char const *fracs = ++ pen;
        val = mystrtol( pen, val );
        neg_exp = pen - fracs;
    }
    if ( ( *pen | ('E'^'e') ) == 'e' ) {
        neg_exp += *++pen == '-'? mystrtol( ++ pen ) : - mystrtol( ++ pen );
    }
    return val * exp_lookup[ neg_exp ];
}
```

Comment: This is an impressive implementation as far as speed is concerned. The exponent and fractional scale tricks are nice. Passing pen by reference makes it suitable for successive calls on number streams, with almost no overhead. Two issues though: 1) the unconditional pre-increment of `pen` may skip the 1st digit char if there's no leading space, this seems like a bug 2) it only deals with positive numbers and only a limited range of floating-point numbers: this should be more explicitly stated.

Comment: please explain that value_t? i can't compile this code!

Comment: @YenDang You need to define that to `float` or `double` or such.

Comment: @arielf-ReinstateMonica Yes, I should have mentioned the unconditional pre-increment. It allows the loop over whitespace to be skipped when it’s only one character. Maybe will edit later.

Comment: why is `val` in the parameters?

Answer (score 12):

C/C++ parsing numbers from text is very slow. Streams are horribly slow but even C number parsing is slow because it's quite difficult to get it correct down to the last precision bit.

In a production application where reading speed was important and where data was known to have at most three decimal digits and no scientific notation I got a vast improvement by hand-coding a floating parsing function handling only sign, integer part and any number of decimals (by "vast" I mean 10x faster compared to `strtod`).

If you don't need exponent and the precision of this function is enough this is the code of a parser similar to the one I wrote back then. On my PC it's now 6.8 times faster than strtod and 22.6 times faster than sstream.

```
double parseFloat(const std::string& input)
{
    const char *p = input.c_str();
    if (!*p || *p == '?')
        return NAN_D;
    int s = 1;
    while (*p == ' ') p++;

    if (*p == '-') {
        s = -1; p++;
    }

    double acc = 0;
    while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9')
        acc = acc * 10 + *p++ - '0';

    if (*p == '.') {
        double k = 0.1;
        p++;
        while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
            acc += (*p++ - '0') * k;
            k *= 0.1;
        }
    }
    if (*p) die("Invalid numeric format");
    return s * acc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I need !

Answer (score 3):

My version that handles exponents too:

```
template<class It>
double mystrtod(It &s, It const end)
{
    static double const pow10[] = { 1E-323, 1E-322, 1E-321, 1E-320, 1E-319, 1E-318, 1E-317, 1E-316, 1E-315, 1E-314, 1E-313, 1E-312, 1E-311, 1E-310, 1E-309, 1E-308, 1E-307, 1E-306, 1E-305, 1E-304, 1E-303, 1E-302, 1E-301, 1E-300, 1E-299, 1E-298, 1E-297, 1E-296, 1E-295, 1E-294, 1E-293, 1E-292, 1E-291, 1E-290, 1E-289, 1E-288, 1E-287, 1E-286, 1E-285, 1E-284, 1E-283, 1E-282, 1E-281, 1E-280, 1E-279, 1E-278, 1E-277, 1E-276, 1E-275, 1E-274, 1E-273, 1E-272, 1E-271, 1E-270, 1E-269, 1E-268, 1E-267, 1E-266, 1E-265, 1E-264, 1E-263, 1E-262, 1E-261, 1E-260, 1E-259, 1E-258, 1E-257, 1E-256, 1E-255, 1E-254, 1E-253, 1E-252, 1E-251, 1E-250, 1E-249, 1E-248, 1E-247, 1E-246, 1E-245, 1E-244, 1E-243, 1E-242, 1E-241, 1E-240, 1E-239, 1E-238, 1E-237, 1E-236, 1E-235, 1E-234, 1E-233, 1E-232, 1E-231, 1E-230, 1E-229, 1E-228, 1E-227, 1E-226, 1E-225, 1E-224, 1E-223, 1E-222, 1E-221, 1E-220, 1E-219, 1E-218, 1E-217, 1E-216, 1E-215, 1E-214, 1E-213, 1E-212, 1E-211, 1E-210, 1E-209, 1E-208, 1E-207, 1E-206, 1E-205, 1E-204, 1E-203, 1E-202, 1E-201, 1E-200, 1E-199, 1E-198, 1E-197, 1E-196, 1E-195, 1E-194, 1E-193, 1E-192, 1E-191, 1E-190, 1E-189, 1E-188, 1E-187, 1E-186, 1E-185, 1E-184, 1E-183, 1E-182, 1E-181, 1E-180, 1E-179, 1E-178, 1E-177, 1E-176, 1E-175, 1E-174, 1E-173, 1E-172, 1E-171, 1E-170, 1E-169, 1E-168, 1E-167, 1E-166, 1E-165, 1E-164, 1E-163, 1E-162, 1E-161, 1E-160, 1E-159, 1E-158, 1E-157, 1E-156, 1E-155, 1E-154, 1E-153, 1E-152, 1E-151, 1E-150, 1E-149, 1E-148, 1E-147, 1E-146, 1E-145, 1E-144, 1E-143, 1E-142, 1E-141, 1E-140, 1E-139, 1E-138, 1E-137, 1E-136, 1E-135, 1E-134, 1E-133, 1E-132, 1E-131, 1E-130, 1E-129, 1E-128, 1E-127, 1E-126, 1E-125, 1E-124, 1E-123, 1E-122, 1E-121, 1E-120, 1E-119, 1E-118, 1E-117, 1E-116, 1E-115, 1E-114, 1E-113, 1E-112, 1E-111, 1E-110, 1E-109, 1E-108, 1E-107, 1E-106, 1E-105, 1E-104, 1E-103, 1E-102, 1E-101, 1E-100, 1E-099, 1E-098, 1E-097, 1E-096, 1E-095, 1E-094, 1E-093, 1E-092, 1E-091, 1E-090, 1E-089, 1E-088, 1E-087, 1E-086, 1E-085, 1E-084, 1E-083, 1E-082, 1E-081, 1E-080, 1E-079, 1E-078, 1E-077, 1E-076, 1E-075, 1E-074, 1E-073, 1E-072, 1E-071, 1E-070, 1E-069, 1E-068, 1E-067, 1E-066, 1E-065, 1E-064, 1E-063, 1E-062, 1E-061, 1E-060, 1E-059, 1E-058, 1E-057, 1E-056, 1E-055, 1E-054, 1E-053, 1E-052, 1E-051, 1E-050, 1E-049, 1E-048, 1E-047, 1E-046, 1E-045, 1E-044, 1E-043, 1E-042, 1E-041, 1E-040, 1E-039, 1E-038, 1E-037, 1E-036, 1E-035, 1E-034, 1E-033, 1E-032, 1E-031, 1E-030, 1E-029, 1E-028, 1E-027, 1E-026, 1E-025, 1E-024, 1E-023, 1E-022, 1E-021, 1E-020, 1E-019, 1E-018, 1E-017, 1E-016, 1E-015, 1E-014, 1E-013, 1E-012, 1E-011, 1E-010, 1E-009, 1E-008, 1E-007, 1E-006, 1E-005, 1E-004, 1E-003, 1E-002, 1E-001, 1E+000, 1E+001, 1E+002, 1E+003, 1E+004, 1E+005, 1E+006, 1E+007, 1E+008, 1E+009, 1E+010, 1E+011, 1E+012, 1E+013, 1E+014, 1E+015, 1E+016, 1E+017, 1E+018, 1E+019, 1E+020, 1E+021, 1E+022, 1E+023, 1E+024, 1E+025, 1E+026, 1E+027, 1E+028, 1E+029, 1E+030, 1E+031, 1E+032, 1E+033, 1E+034, 1E+035, 1E+036, 1E+037, 1E+038, 1E+039, 1E+040, 1E+041, 1E+042, 1E+043, 1E+044, 1E+045, 1E+046, 1E+047, 1E+048, 1E+049, 1E+050, 1E+051, 1E+052, 1E+053, 1E+054, 1E+055, 1E+056, 1E+057, 1E+058, 1E+059, 1E+060, 1E+061, 1E+062, 1E+063, 1E+064, 1E+065, 1E+066, 1E+067, 1E+068, 1E+069, 1E+070, 1E+071, 1E+072, 1E+073, 1E+074, 1E+075, 1E+076, 1E+077, 1E+078, 1E+079, 1E+080, 1E+081, 1E+082, 1E+083, 1E+084, 1E+085, 1E+086, 1E+087, 1E+088, 1E+089, 1E+090, 1E+091, 1E+092, 1E+093, 1E+094, 1E+095, 1E+096, 1E+097, 1E+098, 1E+099, 1E+100, 1E+101, 1E+102, 1E+103, 1E+104, 1E+105, 1E+106, 1E+107, 1E+108, 1E+109, 1E+110, 1E+111, 1E+112, 1E+113, 1E+114, 1E+115, 1E+116, 1E+117, 1E+118, 1E+119, 1E+120, 1E+121, 1E+122, 1E+123, 1E+124, 1E+125, 1E+126, 1E+127, 1E+128, 1E+129, 1E+130, 1E+131, 1E+132, 1E+133, 1E+134, 1E+135, 1E+136, 1E+137, 1E+138, 1E+139, 1E+140, 1E+141, 1E+142, 1E+143, 1E+144, 1E+145, 1E+146, 1E+147, 1E+148, 1E+149, 1E+150, 1E+151, 1E+152, 1E+153, 1E+154, 1E+155, 1E+156, 1E+157, 1E+158, 1E+159, 1E+160, 1E+161, 1E+162, 1E+163, 1E+164, 1E+165, 1E+166, 1E+167, 1E+168, 1E+169, 1E+170, 1E+171, 1E+172, 1E+173, 1E+174, 1E+175, 1E+176, 1E+177, 1E+178, 1E+179, 1E+180, 1E+181, 1E+182, 1E+183, 1E+184, 1E+185, 1E+186, 1E+187, 1E+188, 1E+189, 1E+190, 1E+191, 1E+192, 1E+193, 1E+194, 1E+195, 1E+196, 1E+197, 1E+198, 1E+199, 1E+200, 1E+201, 1E+202, 1E+203, 1E+204, 1E+205, 1E+206, 1E+207, 1E+208, 1E+209, 1E+210, 1E+211, 1E+212, 1E+213, 1E+214, 1E+215, 1E+216, 1E+217, 1E+218, 1E+219, 1E+220, 1E+221, 1E+222, 1E+223, 1E+224, 1E+225, 1E+226, 1E+227, 1E+228, 1E+229, 1E+230, 1E+231, 1E+232, 1E+233, 1E+234, 1E+235, 1E+236, 1E+237, 1E+238, 1E+239, 1E+240, 1E+241, 1E+242, 1E+243, 1E+244, 1E+245, 1E+246, 1E+247, 1E+248, 1E+249, 1E+250, 1E+251, 1E+252, 1E+253, 1E+254, 1E+255, 1E+256, 1E+257, 1E+258, 1E+259, 1E+260, 1E+261, 1E+262, 1E+263, 1E+264, 1E+265, 1E+266, 1E+267, 1E+268, 1E+269, 1E+270, 1E+271, 1E+272, 1E+273, 1E+274, 1E+275, 1E+276, 1E+277, 1E+278, 1E+279, 1E+280, 1E+281, 1E+282, 1E+283, 1E+284, 1E+285, 1E+286, 1E+287, 1E+288, 1E+289, 1E+290, 1E+291, 1E+292, 1E+293, 1E+294, 1E+295, 1E+296, 1E+297, 1E+298, 1E+299, 1E+300, 1E+301, 1E+302, 1E+303, 1E+304, 1E+305, 1E+306, 1E+307, 1E+308 };
    long long b = 0, e1 = 0, e2 = 0;
    bool is_exp = false;
    do
    {
        bool negate = s != end && *s == '-';
        if (s != end && (*s == '-' || *s == '+')) { ++s; }
        bool decimal = false;
        long long &r = is_exp ? e2 : b;
        while (s != end && (*s == '.' || '0' <= *s && *s <= '9'))
        {
            if (*s != '.')
            {
                e1 -= decimal;
                char const digit = *s - '0';
                if (static_cast<unsigned long long>(r) < static_cast<unsigned long long>(r) * 10 + static_cast<unsigned char>(digit))
                {
                    r *= 10;
                    r += digit;
                }
            }
            else { decimal = true; }
            ++s;
        }
        r = negate ? -r : +r;
    } while ((is_exp = !is_exp, is_exp) && s != end && ((*s | ('e' ^ 'E')) == 'e') && (++s, is_exp));
    double const result = b * pow10[323 + (e1 + e2)];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A fast way is to allocate a text buffer or string, read as much as you can into the string, then parse the string.

Your first bottleneck is file I/O.  Second (in order) is converting text into numbers.  You should profile your program as to whether `sscanf` or `std::istringstream` is faster.  Modifications to the I/O portion will yield the biggest performance changes.

To make the process even faster, using multiple threads and double buffering.  One thread reads data into one or more buffers, while another thread parses data out of those buffers.

Additional improvements can be made by changing the data to fixed size fields and records.

Comment: `stringstream` is slow.  I don't know of anything else as ridiculously inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

For C++, working with streams is both much easier and nearly always much slower than using the C interfaces.  However, I suspect that the speed of various C interfaces will depend on their implementation.  `atof` may be faster than `strtod` on one platform, and slower on another.

Personally, I would look at fast ways to read the file, not necessarily fast ways to parse the doubles.  And your fastest ways to read files are almost always platform specific APIs (memory mapped files, scatter/gather I/O, etc.).  So it's very hard to give you an answer that will be the fastest way possible, because that's very platform specific and will change in the future.

Comment: "much slower" might even be an understatement.  When I parse bulk numeric data from text files, it's memory mapped I/O and custom text->double conversion, but `strtod` would only be a minor hit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you've written a lot of brittle code in the hope that it'll be super efficient.  Before attempting all this code, have you even attempted the simple C++ idiomatic solution and determined that it's not fast enough?

```
std::ifstream input("/path/to/file");
if ( !input.is_open() ) {
    // handle error.
}
std::vector<double> numbers;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(input),
    std::istream_iterator(), std::back_inserter(numbers));

// Access item at position (i,j).
double x = numbers[1000*j+i];
```

Keep in mind that the developers behind your standard library vendor's implementation give their best at making this simple code as fast as possible.  It's very likely you'll be able to reach your performance requirements with this trivial piece of code.

On top of that, you get a bunch of freebies:

1. cleans up automatically (manages memory and file handle);
2. automatically resizes for larger inputs;
3. checks for errors when parsing.

Comment: That's nowhere near as fast you'd think.  `istringstream` is miserably slow.

Comment: There's a price to pay for safety and correctness.  There's no point in making the code "as fast as possible" if it doesn't work properly.  Start with a correct solution, then make it fast.

Comment: It's not the strong typing that is slowing it down, it's extra code for handling all kinds of different formats, locales, etc.

Comment: A lot of people need optimization. Just because you don't, doesn't mean istringstream is the answer.