# std::atoll with VC++

Tags: c++, int64, uint64, strtol

I have been using `std::atoll` from `cstdlib` to convert a string to an `int64_t` with gcc. That function does not seem to be available on the Windows toolchain (using Visual Studio Express 2010). What is the best alternative?

I am also interested in converting `strings` to `uint64_t`. Integer definitions taken from `cstdint`.

Comment: it seems this problem is fixed in VS2013 http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/752386/std-atoll-not-found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSVC have _atoi64 and similar functions, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czcad93k(v=VS.100).aspx)

For unsigned 64 bit types, see [_strtoui64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85zk715d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: For anyone else, as a reference, this doesn't seem to have an equivalent for uint64_t, I switched to working with int64_t (casting it from a 3rd party library)

Comment: @Cookie, added link to similar functions for unsigned 64 bit types

Answer (score 5):

- use stringstreams (`<sstream>`)

  ```
  std::string numStr = "12344444423223";
  std::istringstream iss(numStr);
  long long num;
  iss>>num;
  ```
- use boost lexical_cast (`boost/lexical_cast.hpp`)

  ```
   std::string numStr = "12344444423223";
   long long num = boost::lexical_cast<long long>(numStr);
  ```

Comment: @Cookie: You have run a performance test and found that converting a string to a number is your bottleneck?

Comment: valgrind is telling me that e.g. strtod is 8% of total time. atol is a bit behind with 4%. I am actually rewriting strtod to get rid of those 8%. stringstreams are considerably slower than atol. and lexical_cast is the slowest. Most of the time is spent parsing some 100 meg csv.

Comment: The relative costs are not important if the absolute costs are negligible. Does your script run long and/or often enough to justify optimizations? (for learning purposes is of course okay)

Comment: It runs often overnight, and it often runs over 24 hours, if often runs on all 8 cores non-stop, and I often have to wait for it. A 20% difference in performance is very noticeable. Is this really the point here? Is it that hard to accept that I care about performance? Or would you like to dissect my whole project and approach before I am worthy of an answer?

Comment: You do not know then whether strtod() has the same performance on VC++?  `std::sscanf()` might be worth profiling in comparison to std::istringstream.

Answer (score 2):

If you have run a performance test and concluded that the conversion is your bottleneck and should be done really fast, and there's no ready function, I suggest you write your own.
here's a sample that works really fast but has no error checking and deals with only positive numbers.

```
long long convert(const char* s)
{
    long long ret = 0;
    while(s != NULL)
    {
       ret*=10; //you can get perverted and write ret = (ret << 3) + (ret << 1) 
       ret += *s++ - '0';
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Armen, I just might. It is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830868/c-stringstream-is-too-slow-how-to-speed-up for doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [`strtoull`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull) available in your `<cstdlib>`? It's C99. And C++0x should also have [`stoull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404774.aspx) to work directly on strings.

Comment: Sadly, MSVC does not support C99.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 finally has `std::atoll`.