# Why is this macro replaced as 20 instead 10?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

```
1. #define NUM 10
2. #define FOO NUM
3. #undef NUM
4. #define NUM 20
5. 
6. FOO
```

When I only run the preprocessor, the output file contains 20.

However, from what I understand, the preprocessor simply does text replacement. So this is what I think is happening (which is obviously wrong but idky):

1. NUM is defined as 10.
2. Therefore, in line 2, NUM is replaced as 10. So now we have "#define FOO 10".
3. NUM is undefined.
4. NUM is redefined and now is 20.
5. FOO is replaced according to line 2, which was before line 4's redefinition, and is 10.

So I think the output should be 10 instead of 20. Can anything explain where it went wrong?

Comment: Try looking at the preprocessor output rather than guessing the preprocessor output

Comment: Is this a C or a C++ question? These two language are different, please pick one.

Comment: The precise behaviour of the preprocessor is in the standard, there's no need to guess.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Have _you_ tried figuring this out from the standard? I'm a language lawyer, yet 10 minutes in I'm no closer to being able to prove the behaviour.

Comment: check the value of FOO before you redefine NUM. Is it 10 or undefined?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's a fair point. I did understand it once.

Comment: Huh .. failing the word "recursively" being added to `[C99: 6.10.3/9]`, _is_ this even well-defined??

Comment: `FOO` is never defined to be anything other than `NUM`. The laws of text substitution say that `NUM` will be whatever `NUM` is defined to be when it is encountered. At `line 6` `NUM` is defined to be `20`.

Comment: @FUZxxl "_These two language are different_" how?

Comment: "_the preprocessor simply does text replacement_" no, it does tokens replacement

Comment: @curiousguy http://stackoverflow.com/q/640657/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/12887700/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/24397967/995714 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252430/995714

Comment: @OneZero - good question.  I trust it's answered fully.  Counter question: Q: which do you think has done more damage in the history of software development - increasingly abstruse versions of C++, or "language lawyers" who instinctively answer questions like this with "What does the standard say" vs. "How does it actually work"?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc These answers are incorrect. C/C++ is a thing

Comment: @curiousguy In [many different ways](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31505402/417501).

Comment: @curiousguy Please give more explanation before dismissing the provided answers as invalid.

Comment: @fuzxxl: this question is restricted to the preprocessing phases, which are the same in the two languanges.

Comment: @rici Are you sure they are equal? Last time I checked the rules how to form preprocessing tokens for C and C++ were different.

Comment: @fuzxxl, the differences are not relevant to this question, as you know. Tokenization is similarly different between C++ versions, but I have never seen you or anyone else demand a precise version tag because of those differences, unless directly relevant.

Comment: @rici This question pertains a corner case of the preprocessor that could very well be different in the two languages as many corner cases are (I would have to carefully go though the standards to be sure) and you claim the language doesn't matter? Why do you ask for the “why” anyway if you don't care about standards?

Comment: @fuzxxl, i'm not sure who you think i am. It is true that i have been known to ask why on occasion, but here i am not asking anything. You can save yourself the trouble of searching through the standards by readimg my answer below, which might or might not convince you of my concern for the standards. Finally, this is not a "corner case".  It is the algorithm for macro replacement from the beginning, even before there were standards.

Comment: @rici I don't care who you are, but it seems that you have not understood why asking questions as “C/C++” is problematic. But oh well, I can only do so much against tag spammers...

Comment: @FUZxxl: Quite right. I don't understand why asking questions as "C/C++" is problematic, when the wording of both the question and the answer would be identical for both languages. To me, that just seems efficient; why duplicate an entire question and answer, or alternatively leave out an entire potential audience? But I guess that's just me. Anyway, I didn't ask this question, although it appears that you (at one point) thought I did, and in fact I have never asked a question tagged C.

Comment: @rici Well, the answer is *not* equal for both languages. In this case, you are lucky that it is, yet you have to cite both standards to give a correct answer. The point of forbidding C/C++ questions is that there are many questions that just slap on both tags to get the larger audience but if you give an answer in the wrong language they dismiss it and tell you that they are actually programming in C++, not C. And that really sucks a lot. There are also many cases where the question concerns some corner cases that are different between these two or when I would give a different approach for C

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In the interests of collecting all the relevant specifications from the standards, I extracted this information from a comment thread, and added C++ section numbers, based on draft N4527 (the normative text is identical in the two standards). The standard(s) are absolutely clear on the subject.

1. `#define` preprocessor directives do not undergo macro replacement.

   > (C11 §6.10¶7; C++ §16[cpp] ¶6): The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro expansion unless otherwise stated.
2. After a macro is replaced with its replacement text, the new text is rescanned. Preprocessor tokens in the replacement are expanded as macros if there is an active macro definition for the token at that point in the program.

   > (C11 §6.10.3¶9; C++ §16.3[cpp.replace] ¶9) A preprocessing directive of the form
   >
   > `# define identifier replacement-list new-line`
   >
   > defines an *object-like macro* that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive. The replacement list is then rescanned for more macro names as specified below.
3. A macro definition is active from the line following the `#define` until an `#undef` for the macro name, or the end of the file.

   > (C11 §6.10.3.5¶1; C++ §16.3.5[cpp.scope] ¶1) A macro definition lasts (independent of block structure) until a corresponding `#undef` directive is encountered or (if none is encountered) until the end of the preprocessing translation unit. Macro definitions have no significance after translation phase 4.

If we look at the program:

```
#define NUM 10
#define FOO NUM
#undef NUM
#define NUM 20
FOO
```

we see that the macro definition of `NUM` in line 1 lasts exactly to line 3. There is no replaceable text in those lines, so the definition is never used; consequently, the program is effectively the same as:

```
#define FOO NUM
#define NUM 20
FOO
```

In this program, at the third line, there is an active definition for `FOO`, with replacement list `NUM`, and for `NUM`, with replacement list `20`. The `FOO` is replaced with its replacement list, making it `NUM`, and then that is once again scanned for macros, resulting in `NUM` being replaced with its replacement list 20. That replacement is again rescanned, but there are no defined macros, so the end result is that the token `20` is left for processing in translation phase 5.

Comment: Great answer with rigorous explanations. But I still don't understand the need for the "unless otherwise stated" in [cpp]/6. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @belloc: the standard specifies macro expansions in `#if` and `#elif` directives and certain `#include` directives. So it can't say that expansion is never performed in pp directives. What that clause says is that expansion is not performed in any directive except where explicitly indicated.

Answer (score 65):

The text replacement is done where the macro is used, not where you wrote the `#define`. At the point you use `FOO`, it replaces `FOO` with `NUM` and `NUM` is currently defined to be `20`.

Comment: I'm trying to find good wording for this in C99, but failing. Is this actually well-defined?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, sure this is well defined. What difficulties do you have with the wording in the standard? AFAIR it clearly states that at the point of definition only the token sequence is read, and then it describes very precisely how the replacement takes place at point of invocation.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Prove it with a standard quote answering this question, then we'll talk :)

Comment: Preprocessing happens in a single pass. When line 6 is hit, FOO is replaced with NUM. Preprocessing starts again at the beginning of NUM because of this exact issue. Macros that contain other macros. If this didn't subsquently replace the NUM with 20, no macros that call other macros would ever compile

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: C11:6.10.3/9 "A preprocessing directive of the form `# define identifier replacement-list new-line` defines an object-like macro that causes each *subsequent instance* of the macro name to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive. The replacement list is *then* rescanned for more macro names..." The word "then" (my emphasis) clearly states that the rescan is *after* the replacement of a subsequent instance of the name. Also, 6.10.3.5/1 "A macro definition lasts...  until a corresponding #undef directive"

Comment: @rici: I see nothing in that paragraph that disambiguates this case. I think the key is that no replacement occurs _during_ definition, but I can't see that in the text here.

Comment: @lightness: that would be 6.10 para 7: "preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro expansion unless otherwise stated."

Comment: @rici: Okay yep I think between 6.10.3/9 and 6.10/7 that covers it then. :) It would be great to get that in this answer so that it's not just an assertion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: given the velocity of upvotes of this answer, it seems that the vox populi doesn't care that it is just an assertion. :) Nonetheless, I added a language-lawyer-style answer, complete with standards quotes.

Comment: @rici The vox populi were convinced the earth was flat and didn't bother asking for evidence of it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: and when presented with evidence to the contrary, they rose up in opposition. I fear that despite the Enlightenment and the Scientific Revolution, we continue to live in an uncomfortable stew of irrational prejudices, petty obsessions, and wilful blindness to objective reality. (And that's with respect to engineering. When it comes to economics or politics, it goes off the scale.)

Comment: @rici: Right, so let's post some evidence.

Answer (score 20):

In:

```
FOO
```

the preprocessor will replace it with `NUM`, then it will replace `NUM` with what it is currently defined as, which is `20`.

Those initial four lines are equivalent to:

```
#define FOO NUM 
#define NUM 20
```

Answer (score 14):

The C11 standard says (and other versions of C, and C++, say similarly):

> A preprocessing directive of the form `# define identifier replacement-list new-line` defines an object-like macro that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive. The replacement list is then rescanned for more macro names as specified below.

However it also says in another part (thanks to rici for pointing this out).

> The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro expansion unless otherwise stated.

So a subsequent instance of the macro name *which is found inside another `#define` directive* is actually **not** replaced.

Your line `#define FOO NUM` defines that when the token `FOO` is later found (outside of another `#define` directive!), it will be replaced by the token `NUM` .

After a token is replaced, *rescanning* occurs, and if `NUM` is itself a macro, then `NUM` is replaced at that point. (And if whatever `NUM` expands to contains macros , then that gets expanded , and so on).

So your sequence of steps is actually:

1. `NUM` defined as `10`
2. `FOO` defined as `NUM`
3. `NUM` undefined and re-defined as `20`
4. `FOO` expands to `NUM`
5. (rescan) `NUM` expands to `20`

---

This behaviour can be seen in another common preprocessor trick, to turn the defined value of a macro into a string:

```
#define STR(X) #X
#define STR_MACRO(X) STR(X)
#define NUM 10

puts( STR_MACRO(NUM) );     // output: 10
```

If we had written `puts( STR(NUM) )` then the output would be `NUM`.

The output of `10` is possible because, as before, the second `#define` here does not actually expand out `STR`. So the sequence of steps in this code is:

1. `STR(X)` defined as `#X`
2. `STR_MACRO(X)` defined as `STR(X)`
3. `NUM` defined as `10`
4. `STR_MACRO` and `NUM` are both expanded; the result is `puts( STR(10) );`
5. (Rescan result of last expansion) `STR(10)` is expanded to `"10"`
6. (Rescan result of last expansion) No further expansion possible.